# Authenticate HubConnection in Blazor Server with Microsoft Identity platform

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm having a Blazor server project (NET 8.0) with Microsoft Identity platform as Authentication set up. Now I want to implement a chat function with a HubConnection like so:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {

    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chatservice"), options =>
     {
         options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
         {
             //where & how do I get an AccesToken from?
         };
     }).Build();


     hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
     {
         userMessages.Add(new UserMessage { Username = user, Message = message, isCurrentUser = user == usernameInput, DateSent = DateTime.Now });

         this.InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
     });

     await hubConnection.StartAsync();
 }
```

As far as I understood correctly, I'm supposed to authorize the HubConnection, but I don't know how.

This is how my Program.cs looks like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ChatService>();

        builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddHubOptions<ChatService>(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });


        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapBlazorHub();
        app.MapRazorPages();
        app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

        app.MapHub<ChatService>("/chatservice");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Locally everything is working fine. Here's the Error I get when I deploy the project to an Azure App Service:

**Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).**

What am I missing here? Or do I have to adjust my App Registration in Azure AD somehow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working sample. And I have verified and it works fine.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        builder.Services.AddSignalR(s =>
        {
            s.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });

        builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
               new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseResponseCompression();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.MapHub<MainHub>("/mainhub");

        app.MapBlazorHub();
       
        app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

MainHub.cs

```
[Authorize]
public partial class MainHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@using System.Net
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        User:
        <input @bind="userInput" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    #nullable disable
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "Cookies")] public Dictionary<string, string> Cookies { get; set; }

    private HubConnection? hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string? userInput;
    private string? messageInput;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
       
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                 .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/mainhub"), options =>
                 {
                     options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                     var cookieCount = Cookies.Count();
                     var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer(cookieCount);
                     foreach (var cookie in Cookies)
                         cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(
                             cookie.Key,
                             WebUtility.UrlEncode(cookie.Value),
                             path: "/",
                             domain: Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/").Host));
                     options.Cookies = cookieContainer;

                     foreach (var header in Cookies)
                         options.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);

                     options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (input) =>
                     {
                         var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                             {
                                 PreAuthenticate = true,
                                 CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
                                 UseCookies = true,
                                 UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                             };
                         return clientHandler;
                     };
                 })
                 .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                 .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

_Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorApp1.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @* <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" /> *@
    @{
        var CookieCollection = HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
        Dictionary<string, string> Cookies = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var cookie in CookieCollection)
        {
            Cookies.Add(cookie.Key, cookie.Value);
        }
    }
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-Cookies="Cookies" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.razor

```
<CascadingValue Name="Cookies" Value="Cookies">
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
</CascadingValue>
@code {
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string> Cookies { get; set; }
}
```

**Related links**

[Solution: Custom SignalR Endpoints (Hubs) in a Blazor Server Application using Azure B2C When Deployed to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160923/solution-custom-signalr-endpoints-(hubs)-in-a-blaz)

[Azure SignalR service and identity core for Blazor Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77015536/7687666)

Comment: Tried this but it looks like accesToken is null. Unfortunately no change, still 403 forbidden..

Comment: Hi @bbWebDev, Sorry, last time I haven't test it last time, today I have verify it and it's working now. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Trying to make your solution work here, but getting the error: InvalidDataException: Reading 'target' as String failed. Do you know what this could mean? Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @bbWebDev .net7

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately I'm still getting the above mentioned error "reading target as string failed", I can't find anything at all about possible reasons for this error. When running locally the application starts and it immediately displays "Attempting to reconnect to the server".. Please do you have any clue what this could mean? I inserted your code as it is here, didn't change anything (except for the Application name). Could this problem be related to the app registration somehow? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: It must have something to do with "addSignalR" in Program.cs. If I change s.EnableDetailedErrors to false, the error disappears, but obviously the problem is not gone. The application is still in the "Attempting to reconnect" state. What do I have to configure here? Please help..

Comment: Hi @bbWebDev, I am willing to help you, could you share me the detailed steps(like .net version, how to create a brand new project and so on), I will try to write a tutorial for you when I am free.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason!

- Creating a brand new Blazor Server project with .NET 7.0 and Microsoft identity platform as Authentication type (then dotnet msidentity tool is installed automatically)
- Selecting the app registration from Azure
- VS will install all required NuGet packages
- **Additionally I will install "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" manually**
- Then I insert all the code you provided

Comment: @bbWebDev Which one ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/45o19.png

Comment: "Blazor Server App"

Comment: @bbWebDev It's very strange, there is no .net8 option in my side.

Comment: I meant NET 7.0, sorry, typo

Comment: @bbWebDev I will post detailed steps in your another post, please be patient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256725/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-bbwebdev).