# C# Blazor server app using Azure AD and SQL database, Entity Framework and trying to get SignalR or another suggestion to work

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, identity, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an existing Blazor server app that has Entity Framework configured using Azure AD and SQL database. Everything works fine. The client asked to have a separate spreadsheet view that shows every row and column in the database. Their previous solution was Google sheets, so they are just used to using that.

They want to be able to update the patient information from the spreadsheet without having to go into the patient details page I created. I have that spreadsheet view created. Whenever a field/cell is updated, it updates the database.

Now, I am trying to implement another feature that updates all user's screens with any new updates (ex. a user changes the first name of a patient, all other users get that update without refreshing).

I have tried configuring SignalR, but I get an error on the `await hubConnection.StartAsync();` call:

> Invalid negotiation response received.

I have followed a bunch of different guides, but they all result in that error. Some people have said that it has to do with using Microsoft Identity.

Is there something I might be missing, or is there a better way of updating all user's screens with updates? I thought about having a timer that re-queries the database and updates the screens, but that could be bad if a user is in the middle of typing in a field during that refresh.

These are some of the guides that I followed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9bA8elRULI

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

(I found this one in azure on the connection strings section, but it only shows how to implement with javascript)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_SignalR

**UPDATE**:

The more specific error message that I am getting when calling `await hubConnection.StartAsync();` is

> Invalid negotiation response received System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException : '<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 2

I've added the connection string to the `appsetting.json` file

`"Azure": { "SignalR": { "Enabled": true, "ServerStickyMode": "Required", "ConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://######.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=######;Version=1.0;" } },`

In the startup.cs I added

`services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();`

and

`endpoints.MapHub<######>(######.HubUrl);`

chrome says that it has connected

> [2024-01-24T00:05:48.331Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://######.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=1qyojj%2FCBwA%3D&id=######&access_token=######.

I have tried so many different guides, but they all end up with the same error. I have `Azure SignalR` setup. I have granted permission for my user under the `Access Control (IAM)` as well.

I've even gone as far as asking Bing AI, which got me a little further, but still get the same error when running `await hubConnection.StartAsync();`

Also, I get this message when running on localhost. I have not tried on the server because I haven't got that far yet.

Comment: shouldn't be any need to manually mess around with SignalR . Sounds like you are looking for "push notifications" ?   But, regardless of whether you use push-notifications or client polls, you will have to come up with a plan to deal with data changing while another user is editing it. That problem doesn't go away because you use a different communication method.

Comment: wouldn't push notifications require the user to choose allow from the allow notifications popup?

Comment: Hi mtlca401, I've found that when using AD authentication, [using the code in the link works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77844377/7687666).